# Implentation of a Selection Shuffle in Java

Tags: java, shuffle

```
public static void selectionShuffle(int[] values) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = values.length; i > 0; i--) {
         int r = rand.nextInt(i); 
         swap(values, r, i);
    }
//updated answer to include below method
public static void swap(int[]a, int i, int j){
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```

I am writing a card game and need to randomly sort the cards in place, I got an ArrayOutOfBoundsException when I ran the above code, with the compiler complaining particularly about the reassignment from   `values[i] = values[r]` . To be clear, this is , **not** intended to be a selection sort but instead a selection **shuffle**. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `values[i]` should be `values[i-1]`

Comment: Are you sure that the `selectionShuffle` function can really shuffle the cards? And maybe you can find some solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array

Answer (score 0):

Your start condition needs to be `values.length-1`, as Java arrays are `0` to `length-1`.

Also the test should be `>=0`, since as you wrote it'll only go down to index `1`.

```
for(int i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Or as pointed out by Iłya Bursov, you could compare at index `i-1` and leave your for loop conditions as you have them. Not sure what's the best form I always do it as in my example above.

Also, you aren't shuffling. You set the value at index `i` to the one at `r`, but you lost the value that was previously at `i`. You need a temp variable to swap the values.

```
tmp = values[i];
values[i] = values[r];
values[r] = tmp;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may try Collections.shuffle() but it would be more handy if you have to use the wrapper class `Integer` instead of the primitive type `int`at first.

**Integer[] version**:

```
public static void selectionShuffle(Integer[] values) {
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(values));
}
```

**int[] version:**

```
public static void selectionShuffle(int[] values) {
     Integer[] boxedArr = Arrays.stream(values).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
     Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(boxedArr));
     for(int i=0 ; i<values.length ; i++){
         values[i] = boxedArr[i];
     }
 }
```